# "Conductive to achieving" or "Conductive to achieve"?

Tags: verbs, conjunctions

So there is the sentence:
"The current environment is not conducive *to achieving* the best results"
The usage of "to verb+ing" is very confusing.
What is the difference between "to achieving" and "to achieve"?

### Thank you!

Thank you Ricky! I mistakenly typed the wrong word "conductive". You are totally right.

Thank you sooeithdk! You answered my question here. Now I have a clear sense of the gerund phase :)

Comment: First of all I would change 'conductive' to 'conducive' ;-)  https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=conducive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The current environment is not conductive to achieving the best
>   results.

Here, this "achieving" is used as a gerund, an ing-ending noun. This gerund is not a verb, even though it has some verbal characteristics. The rest of the gerund "the best results" finishes this gerund phrase. For more information, click http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/gerund_phrase.htm.

This use of gerund phrase is similar to using noun in this place instead.

> The current environment is not conductive to the *survival of wild
>   animals*.

In this sentence, as you can see, "to" is used as a preposition, not a to-infinitive.

> The current environment is not conductive to achieve the best
>   results.

In this sentence, this "to" is used as a to-infinitive, and also as an adverb phrase. Now, this achieve is a verb. This sentence means that environment is not conductive in order to achieve the best results. To is used to describe the purpose. Therefore,  meaning perfectly changes. Some information about to-infinitive and adverb phrase: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-infinitive, http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/advphr.htm.

I am not sure if "conductive" is the right word here..."helpful" would fit better.

Answer (score 2):

Conducive, not conductive. It is usually followed by a gerund ("ing").

"The current environment is hardly conducive to achieving the best possible results."

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conducive?s=t

Conducive: tending to produce; contributive; helpful; favorable (usually followed by to).

Conductive: having a property or capability of conducting, like a cable.