# Meeting you and to meet you?

Tags: infinitives, gerunds

What is the difference between these two versions:

> 1. I look forward to **meeting** you.
> 2. I look forward to **meet** you.

They seem very similar and exchangeable to me as I am a non-native speaker.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280792/conductive-to-achieving-or-conductive-to-achieve/280794#280794

Answer (score 2):

"To look forward to"  - **It's all about "to"** **which in this case is a preposition, not an infinitive marker.**  And we know that if we use a verb after a preposition, it should be in the gerund.

e.g.

- "I'm looking forward to my holidays."  ("to" followed by a noun)
- "I'm looking forward to my retirement."
- "I'm looking forward to visiting Paris again."
- "I'm looking forward to meeting you."

or "I look forward to ....ing"

Comment: Yes, we look forward to <noun>, we do not look forward to <verb>.  Instead of a noun we can substitute a noun phrase or a noun equivalent such as a gerund.

Answer (score 1):

After the expression "to look forward to", you always use the gerund if you are using a verb.

It has to be: "I look forward to meeting you."

"I look forward to meet you." - This is incorrect.

Comment: See, here's how the game works: I look forward to meet you, I look backward to dismiss you, and I look to the side to annoy you.

Comment: MoniqueH - I agree with your answer except that it is misleading to call a gerund a verb. Look for a definition of 'gerund' in a dictionary. A gerund is a noun made from a verb by adding "-ing."

Comment: @Jim - That is an artificial example that will simply confuse the OP who is confused enough already.